# Can partition be applied to `a -> IO Bool`?

Tags: haskell, monads

I have the following code:

```
import System.Directory
import System.FilePath
import Control.Monad (filterM)

filesAndDirs dir = do
  entries <- getDirectoryContents dir
  let filtered = [dir </> e | e <- entries, e `notElem` [".", ".."]]
  files <- filterM doesFileExist filtered 
  dirs <- filterM doesDirectoryExist filtered 
  return (files, dirs)
```

What I would like to write is something like `return $ partitionM doesFileExist filtered`. Is there a way to reuse or lift `partition` or is the double use of `filterM` the best way?

Comment: You're assuming every element of `filtered` is either a file or a directory. This is not necessarily true.

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/beginners/2009-December/002882.html. This might help.

Comment: @melpomene, yes, that did not occur to me (I just have files and dirs in the locations I'm looking at). It's fine though I'm more curious for the general case, not necessarily for System.Directory functions. @Dave, I'm not the only one to wonder then :). I can't believe google search didn't return this when searching on `partitionM`. It does seem there is not something readily available in the library...

Comment: try searching for "partitionM", with quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A search for `partitionM` on [Hayoo](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html) will return you at least 2 libraries implementing that function. This means that you can either depend on them or study their source.

Here's a more readable translation of [this implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/Extra/latest/doc/html/src/Extra-List.html#partitionM):

```
partitionM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m ([a], [a])
partitionM p xs = foldM f ([], []) xs
  where 
    f (a, b) x = do
      flag <- p x
      return $ if flag 
        then (x : a, b) 
        else (a, x : b)
```

---

Concerning your question on how to lift the `partition` function to `partitionM`, I came up with the following implementation of a lifting function:

```
liftSplitter :: (Monad m) =>
  ((a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])) -> 
  (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m ([a], [a])
liftSplitter splitter kleisliPredicate list = do
  predicateResultsAndItems <- sequence $ do
    item <- list
    return $ do
      predicateResult <- kleisliPredicate item
      return (predicateResult, item)
  return $ results $ predicateResultsAndItems
  where
    results [] = ([], [])
    results ((predicateResult, item) : tail) = (a ++ tailA, b ++ tailB)
      where
        (a, b) = splitter (const predicateResult) [item]
        (tailA, tailB) = results tail
```

You can use this function to lift all functions of type

```
(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
```

(i.e., `partition`, `break` and `span`) to

```
(a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m ([a], [a])
```

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know about Hayoo I'm marking this as accepted. I may change my answer if someone manages to lift partition (as opposed to writing a new partitionM function) or explain why it's not possible.

Comment: @huynhjl It is possible but it is too specialized and will essentially require you to compose a lifting function of the following type signature: `((a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])) -> ((a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m ([a], [a]))`, which won't be easy. As such this function will only be applicable to `partition`. Because of all this it's much more sensible to just implement the `partitionM`.

Comment: Why would it be only applicable to partition and not anything that returns `([a], [a])`, such as `span`, `splitAt`, `break`?

Comment: @huynhjl `splitAt` has a different signature. Concerning `span` and `break` you're correct, this lifting function will work for them too, but that's it, there are no more functions with [that signature](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=(a%20-%3E%20Bool)%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20(%5Ba%5D%2C%20%5Ba%5D)).

Comment: @huynhjl See the updates. I've implemented that lifting function you wanted. Got intrigued by the challenge )